Как передавать переменную в iconCaption ymaps
Передаю в iconCaption переменную, а в итоге нет никакого текста. Может есть другие варианты?
const placemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
            [55.160682, 61.299485],
            {
              iconCaption: variable,
            },
            {
              iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
              iconImageHref: './src/busicon.png',
              iconImageSize: [30, 30],
              iconImageOffset: [-5, -38]
            }
          );


Вы уверены, что ваша переменная содержит какой то текст перед вызовом?

iconCaption — свойство стандартных меток и не подходит для работы с выбранным вами типом 'default#imageWithContent'. Макет в этом случае вы должны создать самостоятельно с помощью templateLayoutFactory по аналогии с нашим примером в песочнице.
